# User-friendly way to append data to Google BigQuery tables

Tags: google-bigquery

We need to manually upload and append raw data to a number of tables every week. I know that this can be done via the BigQuery UI ([official docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#appending_to_or_overwriting_a_table_with_csv_data)) by "creating" a new table with the same name and setting the "Append to table" flag.

However, I'm a bit nervous doing this repeatedly incase the uploader makes a mistake (e.g. sets overwrite instead of append). My questions are:

1. Is there a simpler way to append the data? The current UI can be intimidating and error prone for a non-technical person.
2. Can I restrict permissions so that a user has append-only permissions for a given table?

We've been appending the data manually as mentioned in the official docs, but I need some system to prevent human errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incase anyone looks at this in the future, we managed to solve this via Google Sheets App Scripts.

There is a Google Sheets API that is fairly easy to use: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/bigquery

We added header and data validations in our app script as well, which makes the whole process foolproof.